# How to save an image in upload folder from bytes string of image?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to save an image in particular folder. here i am using image bytes string to upload. i am using "imagecreatefromstring($bytesarray)" for this. and "imagejpeg()" which is given me a jpeg image which i passed in imagecreatefromstring() function.

here i am using file_put_contents() for uploading an image. but the image still not  save in folder.

Here below is my code.

```
$imgdata = base64_decode($fl_data[$i]['Archivo']);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($imgdata);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');                
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);

$filemainpath = base_url().'uploads/apifiles/'.$filename.".".$extension;
file_put_contents($filemainpath, $im);
```

Comment: Use directory path (//__DIR__//) instead of base_url().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the folder permission to 777 and use absolute path instead of base_url()

```
$filemainpath = __dir__.'../uploads/apifiles/'.$filename.".".$extension;
```

Comment: I used this.. but still the image is not save in folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
$filemainpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/YourAppName/uploads/apifiles/".$filename.".".$extension;
```